# how to access photo library of device (iphone/ipod) from mac application?

Tags: macos

I'm writing an Mac Desktop application. I'm wondering if I can get a list of files/filenames of the photos stored in the iPhone/iPod library connected through USB.

I searched for it, and found some links but dont know how to proceed :
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/AccessingHardware/AH_Finding_Devices/AH_Finding_Devices.html

I will appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Why not require the user to keep his/her iOS device's photos sync'd up with iCloud Photo Stream and then you can avoid having to mess with connecting to the device via USB?  Going through USB might not even be app functionality you can get up on the Apple App Store, if that's how you want to sell your software.

Comment: thanks michael for the suggestion, but i want to access the photos from the devices which are connected to the system. (eg. if two devices are connected to the system, then we need to access photos of both the devices to the mac application.)